# Where can i check all the rules, best practices of pylint?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

source to check pylint rules?
I am using pylint , but i need documentation to check all pylint rules.

Answer (score 7):

[This page of Pylint documentation](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html) appears to contain a complete list of Pylint's checkers and messages for each checker. I found it with a quick Google search for "pylint rules documentation," in case that helps you find the answer on your own for any similar questions in the future.